# Why my faces were created at an angle?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I created edge loop cut and extrude this 2 faces which Y constraint. But the side face is slanted a little but. WHy this could have occured?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand, slanted on what axis? Are you in othographic view? Maybe share your objects if it helps to understand: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Moonboots. Thank you. I solved it. I scaled them on the axis to 0 and it become vertical edge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply made a mistake somewhere and moved something that you did not notice. That's it. There is no conspiracy or magic here. This happens all the time to pretty much everybody.

Comment: Ok. I will try recreating faces.

Comment: I scaled edge on the relevant axis to 0 and it become vertical.